# Trying to run a simple app with UITextField - Simulator is crashing

Tags: iphone, uitextfield

I have two UITextFields in the App as IBOutlets and I have made a connection from File's Owner to these ... When I run Build and Go, the iphone simulator crashes ... and in the console (after debugging) ... its showing me following ...

```
2009-08-22 18:11:40.869 Control_Fun[1138:20b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] loaded the "Control_FunViewController" nib but the view outlet was not set.'
```

However, I am not having any outlet (IBOutlet) explicitly defined as view ... is this something hidden? When I Control Click File's Owner and drag it to the UITextFields, it giving me three options in the gray pop-up menu to connect to

```
1. nameField (declared as IBOutlet property in the header file)
2. numberField (declared as IBOutlet property in the header file)
3. view (where is this coming from?)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out - It was a View-Based Application template from where I started so there was a parent View which was defined as a outlet (by default) and it still needed to be set (with File's Owner - in this case) ... working now.